# Is the Fifth Doctor's personality in 'Time Crash' in line with his personality originally on the tv show?

Tags: doctor-who

I've only ever seen the Fifth Doctor in 'The Five Doctors' (about 20 years ago though) and Time Crash. I was under the assumption Five and Ten were very similar but Five in 'Time Crash' seems more crotchety, as if he's channelling the First Doctor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fifth Doctor wasn't known for being crotchety, but I suspect that having the tenth Doctor tease him about his hat, weight, and so on after hijacking his time line by forgetting to raise his shields or whatever it was would bring out anyone's bad mood. :)

As an interesting side note, Peter Davidson (5th doctor) is David Tennant's (10th doctor) father in law, as David Tennant is married to Davidson's daughter Georgia Moffet, who also played "Jenny" in the Doctor Who episode "The Doctor's Daughter".

How about that for keeping it in the family eh? :)

Comment: And given that David Tennant has said that the Fifth Doctor was his favorite Doctor, things get a bit more interesting since he's now his father in law.